# Orange3 in 64bit and pandas

Tags: pandas, orange

Is there a way to use Orange3 in a 64bit system and fill tables with pandas dataframe ?

There is no table_from_dataframe method, so I guess no.

Also, is there a way to get infos and some news about Orange developpement ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow [Orange development on GitHub](https://github.com/biolab/orange3).

There seems to be a ["pandas" feature branch](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/pull/1347) that hasn't been merged yet.

I'm using Orange as a 64-bit process on a non-Windos platform (specifically, [Debian](http://www.debian.org/)). As far as I know, it comes 64-bit by default, except, of course, on Windos.

Comment: Yes I see it. But I haven't found information about when the commit is scheduled or if there is going to be a commit at all.

Comment: @Coolpix I agree it's in everyone's best interest to have pandas support. Perhaps you can help them by doing the hard work? :)

Comment: Not good enought :D I understand I will wait gently or find something else ^^ thanks